# Seed umbrella project (Ecto/Postgre)

Tags: elixir, ecto

I currently have an umbrella project containing a database service. I would like to seed this service automatically when I run the `mix test` command but I can't.

---

I tried to put into `apps/db_service/mix.ex` the following code

```
defp aliases do
    [
        "ecto.setup": ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
        "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
        "test": ["ecto.reset", "test"]
    ]
end
```

but I got an error if I run `mix test` on the root directory : `** (Mix) The database for DatabaseService.Repo couldn't be dropped: ERROR 55006 (object_in_use)` (command is working into the service directory)

---

So I tried to put into `root/mix.ex`

```
defp aliases do
    [
        "test": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "test"]
    ]
end
```

and into `apps/db_service/mix.ex`

```
defp aliases do
    [
        "test": ["run priv/repo/seeds.exs", "test"]
    ]
end
```

but now, I get the following error : `** (Mix) No such file: priv/repo/seeds.exs`

---

How can I do for seed my tests and have the `mix test` command works in the root and in the service folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a late answer but it is here:

```
defp aliases do
  "test.seed": ["run #{Path.join(__DIR__, "priv/repo/seeds.exs")}"],
  test: ["test.seed", "test"]
end
```

Taken from [this response](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/8358#issuecomment-441186023) on Github.

Answer (score -1):

When you have to do the `mix test`, use `MIX_ENV=test mix test`.  And for running the tasks in test database we need to specify the environment, as for test env seperate DB is created.

So use `MIX_ENV=test` and then command, so that it run the tasks on the test database.

Comment: My test database is perfectly working. That's not the problème.

Comment: Are you able to run seeds.exs on the terminal directly. Without using in within the tasks.

Comment: I can run it with a `mix run`